# Requesting advice on persisting objects from a dynamic language to a document database

Tags: python, mongodb, orm, dynamic-languages, nosql

Do you have any insights into the most elegant way of persisting objects from a dynamic language in a document database?

I have a solid background in C# and have just started programming in Python. At the same time I am trying to learn the ropes of MongoDB.

Now I am wondering: what is the most elegant way to persist my data to the MongoDB database? I have considered several approaches:

1. Make all my Python classes able to create a graph of dictionaries and lists representing their state. Moreover, make them able to initialize their state from such a graph. When I want to persist an object, I will ask it for its graph representation and persist that. When I want to get an object, I will retrieve a document graph and provide this to the `__init__` method of my class.
2. Create a separate Mapper class capable of inspecting a given object and creating a graph of dictionaries and lists, which I may then store in MongoDB. The mapper would also be responsible for creating objects whose data has been retrieved from the database.
3. I tried out [mongoengine](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mongoengine/0.2.2), a document-object mapper. However, I was disappointed when it forced me to derive my classes from a particular class (Document). It reminded me of Microsoft's Entity Framework 1.0 and the lack of POCO support. I don't want to be forced to derive from a particular class. It doesn't feel right, but I am unsure whether this is really a problem in a dynamic language.

Is my thinking being hindered by my background in C#? I am sure I haven't grokked the extent of the flexibility that a dynamic language provides, so any advice or hints at best practices would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python defines several special methods such as [**getstate**](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html?highlight=__getstate__#object.__getstate__) and many others to allow your classes to define exactly how best to serialize and de-serialize their instances.  They're all used internally by the `pickle` module (which then uses this information to produce a "blob", i.e. a string of bytes, and restore objects from such blobs), but, if you want better indexing obtained by storing graphs directly rather than via opaque blobs, it's basically a question of tweaking the `pickle` procedures to stop just before turning the graphs into blobs.  I think you'll have to do it by copy-paste-edit of `pickle.py` (as it's not designed to be customized in this way by more elegant methods such as subclassing), but that should still save you lots of work wrt redoing it all from scratch.

I believe this approach lies somewhere between your options 1 and 2 -- classes need to define such special methods only in response to specific needs, and most of the work needed to orchestrate the various possibility will be handled by your pickle-variant (much as it's handled by pickle itself for the "normal" case where the serialized form is a blob).